# How to load the data in table view from Sqlite Database and the state of UISwitch is according to the save state in Database

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to load data in `TableView` from DataBase(SQlite) and the `UISwitch` state in set according to the save state (ON/OFF) in `DataBase`. Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParentalMovieTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ParentalMovieTableViewCell

    let db = xxxDataBase()
    lockArray = db.getLockInfo(catg: tabName)
    if lockArray.isEmpty == true
    {
        cell.itemLbl.text = parentalMovieArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemSwitch.isOn = true
        cell.itemSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.itemSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    else
    {
        cell.itemLbl.text = parentalMovieArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.itemSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    for i in parentalMovieArray
    {
        for j in lockArray{

            if i == j.item
            {
                cell.itemSwitch.isOn = true
            }
            else
            {
                cell.itemSwitch.isOn = false

            }
        }
    }        
}

@objc func switchChanged(_sender:UISwitch!)
{
   // print("Table view switch changed\(_sender.tag)")
   // print("The switch is\(_sender.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
    if _sender.isOn == false
    {
        print(_sender.tag)
        var value = parentalMovieArray[_sender.tag]
        print(value)
        restrictMovieArray.append(value)

        print(restrictMovieArray)
    }
    else if _sender.isOn == true
    {
        print(_sender.tag)
        var value1 = parentalMovieArray[_sender.tag]
        print(value1)
        if let index = restrictMovieArray.index(of: value1) {
            restrictMovieArray.remove(at: index)
            print(restrictMovieArray)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `for i in parentalMovieArray` loop makes no sense. `cellForRowAt` is called once for each row.

Comment: Thanks for correction.. Please tell me any solution my problem is that... (I have a tableView in which every cell contains a label and a switch.. When the data load in tableView the all switches show ON state.. I want when user turn off any switch and press done Button the switches state either On or Off can save in database and when user reopen the application the Data comes from the database and the Switches show according to the save switch state (on/off) not all On or Off..)

Answer (score 1):

1-)Retrieving data from a database in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` delegate method is actually very costly, since it will be called many times especially when user scrolls, it kills your applications performance, common solution is to fetch data in  `viewDidLoad` store it in a viewcontrollers member and use it when you need to.

2-) `if lockArray.isEmpty == true` and `else` blocks first 3 lines are the same so you can move it below those blocks.

and can you clarify your question please?

Comment: I have a tableView in which every cell contains a label and a switch.. When the data load in tableView the all switches show ON state.. I want when user turn off any switch and press done Button the switches state either On or Off can save in database and when user reopen the application the Data comes from the database and the Switches show according to the save switch state (on/off) not all On or Off..

Comment: Assuming you have a custom `UITableViewCell` containing a switch, you have to listen change event of the switch, and inform the containing viewcontroller via delegate methods (which you should implement).Store the switch values of cell's in a  `Array`. Then you should also listen tap event of "Done" button, so you can update your Database when user taps.